# Running script on shared Google Sheets file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a container-bound script that takes the active cell in whatever active sheet the user is using in a Google Sheets to compose an email to send out. The code worked perfectly until I shared it with multiple users who all have 'can edit' rights to the spreadsheet. Now the script doesn't seem to run, it won't even post logs that I have embedded in the script, and no execution record shows up in the script editor.

Here is the main function's code (sendEmailSheet), which calls two other functions I have in the script file:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('emailsFromSheet')
      .addItem('Run Script!', 'sendEmailSheet')
      .addToUi();
}//without this there is no trigger under the add-ons menu

function sendEmailSheet(){
  Logger.log('the function at least starts'); 
  try {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('couldn\'t get active sheet: ' + e);}

  Logger.log(sheet);
  try{
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName(); }
  catch (e) {
    console.error('couldn\'t get sheet name: ' + e);
  }
  Logger.log(sheetName);
  if(sheetName == "sendEmail"){
    sendEmailTemplate(sheet);
  }
  else if(sheetName == "createDraft"){
    createDraftTemplate(sheet); 
  }
  else{ //catch errors
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('There is an error, perhaps one of the sheets is named incorrectly. Please keep the sheets named "sendEmail" and "createDraft", and restart the add-on.');
  }
}
```

Is it because now there are several users, so SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() won't work since there could be conflicting 'active' sheets? But I thought the code would still just run independently for each user...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Use Stackdriver to log things, as it will actually persist logs in a useful manner: `console.log`. You can log multiple things in a single log message, e.g. `console.log({message: "some message", somekey: somevalue, key1: [arrayval1, arrayval2, ...], key4: {key1:"some object value", ....}, ... });` Be sure to check your scopes and that you have granted it permission (i.e. run a function from the Script Editor)

Comment: The users probably need to authorize permissions.  It might be considered a security risk for code to run that the user did not authorize.   Try having a user open the script editor, and run the code from the code editor and see if they get a prompt to authorize the services needed.